# Why the FrameworkElement.FindName(string) method returns null in my case?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

WPF, .NET 4.6.1

Why the `FrameworkElement.FindName(string)` method returns `null` in my case?

```
class Sandbox {

    const string listBoxName = "lb";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Window win = new Window();

        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.Name = listBoxName;

        win.Content = lb;
        win.IsVisibleChanged += Win_IsVisibleChanged;

        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(win);
    }

    private static void Win_IsVisibleChanged(Object sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        if ((bool)e.NewValue) {

            Window win = sender as Window;
            var lb = win.FindName(listBoxName); // null
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the element has child elements, these child elements are all
>   searched recursively for the requested named element.

My `lb` is child element of `win` object, but `win.FindName(listBoxName)` can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in MSDN documentation you linked that:

> FindName operates within the current element's namescope.

Where namescope is XAML namescope. Those scopes are created when control tree is built from XAML. When you build the tree yourself, when no XAML is involved at all (like in your case) - no such scopes are created by default. That means no controls are registered in XAML scope because there is no such scope at all. You can read more about XAML scopes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, if you want to you can create scope yourself and register your name:

```
class Program {
    const string listBoxName = "lb";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Window win = new Window();
        // create scope and associate it with Window
        NameScope.SetNameScope(win, new NameScope());
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.Name = listBoxName;
        // register "lb" name
        win.RegisterName(listBoxName, lb);

        win.Content = lb;
        win.IsVisibleChanged += Win_IsVisibleChanged;

        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(win);
    }

    private static void Win_IsVisibleChanged(Object sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        if ((bool) e.NewValue) {

            Window win = sender as Window;
            var lb = win.FindName(listBoxName); // null
            Console.WriteLine(lb);
        }
    }
}
```